# Exce4Macro Print code needs changing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro written by someone else with which ends -

```
    End If

ExecuteExcel4Macro "PRINT(1,,,1,,,,,,,,2,,,TRUE,,FALSE)"

Sheets("policy data").Select
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Instead of Printing directly, I need to change this so that I print to pdf to file and save

Can I amend this existing code ?

Thanks